# GIT error message

Tags: git, merge, head

I am getting a git error message when I do a pull that I need to do a Git Merge.

In my remote Repo(not Local) i do see a pushed commit of the code but I cant find it in the branch it was supposed to be pushed to. In fact it I don't see the commit to any branches in the repo but when I look at the individual commits the code resides on the repo. The gif below shows that the version absolutely resides on my remote repo. 
[image]

From Git Bash on local machine is shown in excerpt below.

```
$ git log
commit 3452a610faa4bdeb690a6711652a7c28b770b296
Author: user <user@anonymous.com>
Date:   Wed Jun 28 13:29:04 2017 -0700

    PIC_FIRMWARE_VERSION "00.22.27"
    Changed Structure 
    Added loop to transfer....etc etc

$ git status
HEAD detached at PICver00.22.27
nothing to commit, working tree clean
```

When I look in my local repository and visualize all branch history, I do see the GUI info as below. Don't mind the message since there is only a version number difference between 00.22.29 and 00.22.27. Other than that functionally they are the same. 
[image]

and when i do a pull from remote repo i see this
[image]

I can fix the merge conflict but here are my questions.
Q1) I am wondering why even when remote repo has a source code of my local 00.22.29 changes it doesn't show up in any branches. It does mean that I pushed it but it didnt end up in the intended branch. In fact I don't see it on any branches, like its orphaned. I wonder what mistake i did.

Comment: It is very hard to answer your question because you're all over the place. You say `git push` require you to do a merge. This means you have at least one commit locally that the remote doesn't have, and the remote have at least one commit that you don't have locally. As to *how* this happened, only you can tell. As to how to fix this, execute a `git pull`.

Comment: Git pull requires for a merge since there are conflicts. The tip of the remote repository is at least one commit behind and so requires me to merge. But the question is that the commit is there but the its not visible under any branches in repo.

Comment: `git log` shows the log from where you're currently at. Try `git log --all`.